# How Do I Select From Two Different Tables in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have these `Models` and I want to be able to select from the first two.

```
class Comments(models.Model):
    post_id = models.ForeignKey('Posts')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=480)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField()

class Posts(models.Model):
    user_id = models.ForeignKey('Users')
    content = models.CharField(max_length=480)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField()

class Users(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    time_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to be able to select posts and their comments and have them ordered by `datetime` so that `Posts` and `Comments` will be mixed when displaying them. 
I think Twitter does the same thing with their `Tweets` and `Retweets`.

Comment: You may want to look into [Many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: @Celeo: I don't understand how Many-to-Many relationship will suffice here since a `Post` can't be made by many `Users` and likewise a `Comment` belong to many post. Can you shed more light?

Comment: I should have linked [many-to-one](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might not be able to do it with a single query. However, you can get the two querysets and use itertools to merge the two iterables.

Example, assuming you want the users' posts and comments,

```
posts = user.posts_set.all() #or Posts.objects.filter(user=user)
comments = Comments.objects.filter(post_id__user=user)

import itertools
qs = itertools.chain.from_iterable([posts, comments])
```

Alternatively, if you are not slicing the queryset,

```
qs = posts | comments
```

Now, you can order by key:

```
qs_sorted = sorted(qs, key=lambda x: x.time_created)
```

You might want to limit the queryset to avoid unusual loading times, as the querysets are evaluated int he `sorted` function

Comment: Thank you but how do I then know which comment is for which post? I can't see the relationship in the query.

Comment: You can use `hasattr(obj, post_id)` to see if it is a comment or not.. This was an example, but you can pretty much use any unique  attribute to check for the type.

Answer (score 0):

To select a certain group of Posts:

```
filtered_posts = Posts.objects.filter(however_you_filter_your_queryset)
```

To get all of the Comments associated with a certain post:

```
related_comments = p.comments_set.all()
```

You could create a list of tuples where each holds `(data_type, content, time)`:

```
tuple_list = []
for p in filtered_posts:
    post_tuple = ('post', p.content, p.time_created)
    tuple_list.append(post_tuple)
    related_comments = p.comments_set.all()
    for c in related_comments:
        comment_tuple = ('comment', p.content, p.time_created)
        tuple_list.append(comment_tuple)
```

You ultimately end up with a list of tuples containing all of the posts you grabbed along with the comments related to those posts. If you sort your list by the third element of the tuples, you'll be sorting by the `datetime` field you're after. You can also remove duplicates by making a `set()`.